# Reading list of files in a directory and copying the contents using batch command file

Tags: windows, file, csv, batch-file, text

I have a list of csv files in a directory which have name with format XX_YYYFile.csv, where XX is a name that can have any characters (including space), and YYY is random 3 digits. For example: "book_123File.csv", "best movie_234File.csv", etc. I want to read this list of files then create new CSV files by removing "_YYYFile". The content of the new files are the same with the original ones, except the first line needs to be added with value "number,name,date".

```
set inputFileFolder=C:\Input
set outputFileFolder=C:\Output
FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('DIR %inputFileFolder%\*File.csv /B /O:D') DO (
    set reportInputFile=%inputFileFolder%\%%F
    set reportInputFileName=%%F
    set result=!reportInputFileName:~0,-12!
    set reportOutputFileName=!result!.csv
    set reportOutputFile=%outputFileFolder%\!result!.csv
    echo number,name,date > !reportOutputFile!
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (!reportInputFile!) do (
        echo %%a >> !reportOutputFile!
    )
)
```

If I run this batch file, file "book.csv" is successfully created with the correct contents (first line: "number,name,date", the next lines are from file "book_123.csv"). But file "best movie_234.csv" and other files contain space in the filename are not created successfully. File "best movie.csv" is created with only 1 line "number,name,date". The contents of file "best movie_234.csv" are not copied to file "best movie.csv".

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) properly. Note the [`usebackq` parameter](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) in inner `for /F` loop as well:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "inputFileFolder=C:\Input"
set "outputFileFolder=C:\Output"
FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('DIR "%inputFileFolder%\*File.csv" /B /O:D') DO (
    set "reportInputFile=%inputFileFolder%\%%F"
    set "reportInputFileName=%%F"
    set "result=!reportInputFileName:~0,-12!"
    set "reportOutputFileName=!result!.csv"
    set "reportOutputFile=%outputFileFolder%\!result!.csv"

    >"!reportOutputFile!" echo number,name,date

    for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in ("!reportInputFile!") do (
       >>"!reportOutputFile!" echo %%a
    )

        rem above `for /f ... %%a ...` loop might be replaced by FINDSTR
    rem >>"!reportOutputFile!" findstr "^" "!reportInputFile!"

        rem                                                or by TYPE
    rem >>"!reportOutputFile!" type "!reportInputFile!"  
)
```

**Hint**: each [`>` and `>>` redirector](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) works as follows:

- *opens* specified oputput file, then
- *writes* something to oputput file, and finally
- *closes* oputput file.

This procedure might be extremely slow if repeated in next `for /f ... %%a ...` loop  for larger files:

```
    >"!reportOutputFile!" echo number,name,date
    for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in ("!reportInputFile!") do (
       >>"!reportOutputFile!" echo %%a
    )
```

Use block syntax rather:

```
    >"!reportOutputFile!" (
    echo number,name,date
        for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in ("!reportInputFile!") do (
           echo %%a
        )
    )
```

above `for /f ... %%a ...` loop might be replaced by [`FINDSTR` command](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) (it *eliminates* empty lines like `for` does) as follows:

```
    >"!reportOutputFile!" (
         echo number,name,date
         findstr "^." "!reportInputFile!"
    )
```

or by [`TYPE` command](http://ss64.com/nt/type.html) (it will *retain* empty lines unlike `for`) as follows:

```
    >"!reportOutputFile!" (
         echo number,name,date
         type "!reportInputFile!"  
    )
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working fine now. I will use the TYPE command instead because it's much faster.